# Setting HTTP status code in Bottle?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, bottle

How do I set the HTTP status code of my response in Bottle?

```py
from bottle import app, run, route, Response

@route('/')
def f():
    Response.status = 300 # also tried `Response.status_code = 300`
    return dict(hello='world')

'''StripPathMiddleware defined:
   http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#ignore-trailing-slashes
'''

run(host='localhost', app=StripPathMiddleware(app()))
```

As you can see, the output doesn't return the HTTP status code I set:

```bsh
$ curl localhost:8080 -i
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 19 May 2013 18:28:12 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json

{"hello": "world"}
```

Comment: does `from bottle import response; response.status = 300` work? http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.response

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I believe you should be using [`response`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.response)

`from bottle import response; response.status = 300`

Answer (score 26):

Bottle's built-in response type handles status codes gracefully.  Consider something like:

```
return bottle.HTTPResponse(status=300, body=theBody)
```

As in:

```
import json
from bottle import HTTPResponse

@route('/')
def f():
    theBody = json.dumps({'hello': 'world'}) # you seem to want a JSON response
    return bottle.HTTPResponse(status=300, body=theBody)
```

Comment: dm03514's answer was what I was looking for. Gives me everything I was after, without requiring any changes to my code (apart from renamed from `Response` to `response`.

Answer (score 0):

## raise can be use to get more power with HTTPResponse to show the status code (200,302,401):

Like you can simply do this way:

```
import json
from bottle import HTTPResponse

response={}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
response['status'] ="Success"
response['message']="Hello World."
result = json.dumps(response,headers)
raise HTTPResponse(result,status=200,headers=headers)
```